# Cannot update grub.cfg, Device file sys_uuid missing

Tags: linux, grub, uuid

using Rocky Linux 9

I modified the grub boot line with an extra kernel parameter, update grub

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/rocky/grub.cfg
```

After reboot, i can see the boot line modification persisted. check. since then, I have had a BIOS update to address the root cause of the workaround I had with the kernel boot line modification above.
So now I am trying to undo the kernel boot line just like before:

```
sudo vi /etc/defaults/grub
```

save & exit

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/rocky/grub.cfg
```

however, this now fails with:

```
Generating grub configuration file...
    Device file sys_uuid naa.long-string-of-alpha-numerics PVID <UUID-that-matches-root-partition-UUID-output-from-lsblk-f> last seen on /dev/sda not found
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware settings ...
done
```

On reboot, the GRUB kernel boot line was not updated with my change.  I'm sure it has something to do with this 'Device file' message but it doesn't look to be erroring out...

anyone?

**UPDATE**

tried resetting GRUB by following this here :[RHeL, 9.3. Resetting GRUB] [1](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/assembly_reinstalling-grub_managing-monitoring-and-updating-the-kernel#:%7E:text=You%20can%20reinstall%20GRUB%20using%20the%20yum%20reinstall%20command.&text=Important-,Ensure%20that%20the%20system%20does%20not%20cause%20data%20corruption%20or,issuing%20the%20yum%20reinstall%20command.&text=Enter%20the%20yum%20reinstall%20command,efi%20and%20shim%20bootloader%20files.) without success, same behavior: complains about not finding the device file, grub.cfg does not reflect changes made to /etc/defaults/grub.
So, it would seem this issue is not directly related to grub...but where then...still investigating

**Update 2**

so reinstalling udev:

```
sudo dnf reinstall udev
```

Did succeed in restoring a default kernel boot line, however, I still cannot regenerate grub.cfg with the same errors as before.
However, also alarming, by following the instructions for 'resetting GRUB' I no longer have /etc/default/grub, the file is gone now.  I tried to reinstall grbu2-efi with no success: the file is gone.